# PHPStorm: phpstorm unable to resolve column $1

Tags: php, postgresql, phpstorm

При использовании параметризованного SQL, например:

```
pg_prepare($db, 'query', 'select * from table where id=$1');
```

PHPStorm выдает "unable to resolve column '$1'". В целом - не смертельно, но отключать этот тип предупреждения не хочется, а чистота анализа портится.

Это как-нибудь можно "вылечить"? В настройках проекта диалект SQL выставлен правильно.

Comment: Посмотрите, не ваш ли это случай: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20458#comment=27-602210 ?

Comment: обычно рядом с такими вещами всплывает иконка горящей лампочки, там в подменю должны быть способы проставить аннотацию в текущем месте (аннотация "на весь файл" обычно не работает).

Comment: Нет, тут предупреждение срабатывает именно на $1, то есть на placeholder для последующего подставления значения при выполнение pg_execute.